# Is it possible to use CouchDB as wordpress primary db?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, couchdb

When setting up wordpress localy in my Virtualbox ubuntu image. i input couchdb credentials as the default db for wordpress, but it is failing to connect to my couchdb host saying,

> This either means that the username and password information in your
>   wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database
>   server at `http://192.168.92.1:8101/`. This could mean your
>   host's database server is down.
>
> ```
> Are you sure you have the correct username and password? **yes**
> Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname? **yes**
> Are you sure that the database server is running? **yes**
> ```

My couchdb database is up and running in `http://192.168.92.1:8101/`. And crated a db called wordpress there.

My question is, Is it possible to integrate couchdb with wordpress if so what is the wrong with my configuration?
and my last question is:

**Is there any CMS system that can integrate with couchDB such as [markuso](http://www.markuso.com/essay/project-kleks) like we integrate  Wordpress with mysql?**

Comment: In general, you can only substitute databases if the client app (e.g. WP) is using absolutely pure standard SQL, with no DB-specific function calls/syntax, and is using a proper DB abstraction library, like PDO. I refuse to dig in WP's disgusting innards to check, but if it's using (say) mysqli, then no, you can't use couch because couch's DB calls use entirely different PHP-level functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nope. wordpress requires mysql.
https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/